# Unclosed tag on line 1: 'block'. Looking for one of: endblock

Tags: django-templates

I have read the other answers on this topic and still do not see what I am missing. Not sure if it is something with vs code and the extensions I have added as I type out code as per the training video and when I save the code it get compressed?

My base.html file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>{% block page_title %}{% endblock page_title %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content%}
  </body>
</html>
```

The code in the index file where I want to use the base.html format, looks like this after I have saved it. As you can see vs code compress it - is that the issue and if so how do I fix?

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block page_title %} All challenges {% endblock
page_title %} {% block content %}
<ul>
  <li><a href="{% url 'month-challenge' month %}">{{ month|title}}</a></li>
</ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

The extensions I have is Django Template, Prettier, Django I am thinking it is something with my preferences that cause this.
I have re-typed and double check the spacing around the {% to make sure as I see that is the most common solution.
I have also tried the just using {% endblock %} without the block names but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code Prettier extension auto format page so title block is start with first line and end with second line.

html templete can't understand DTL(jinja) reading so django tempale engine fatch an error

so just rearrange it like this...

```
{% extends "base.html" %} 
{% block page_title %} All challenges {% endblockpage_title %} 
{% block content %}
     <ul>
       <li><a href="{% url 'month-challenge' month %}">{{ month|title}}</a></li>
     </ul>
{% endblock content %}
```